# How do i fix the 'element not found' in binary search?

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, binary-search

I have been trying to implement this code whose work is to find a particular element using Binary search.Now the code works fine if element is present in the list but it is unable to display the intended block if the search element is not present.I have assumed that the list is sorted in ascending order.Help on this would be appreciated

I have tried giving an else part with the while: but it doesn't help.Its unable to show the error for element not found

```
def binarysearch(l,item):
    low=0
    u=len(l)-1
    while low<=u:
        mid=int((low+u)/2)
        if item==l[mid]:
            return mid
        elif item<l[mid]:
            high=mid-1
        else:
            low=mid+1
l=eval(input("Enter the list of elements"))
item=int(input("Enter search item:"))
index=binarysearch(l,item)
if index>=0:
    print(item,"found at index",index)
else:
    print("Element not found") #i am unable to reach this part
```

If input is:
Enter the list of elements[8,12,19,23]
Enter search item:10

I expect the result to be "Element not found" .but the program does nothing in this situation

Answer (score 0):

I will give you a tip and later on I will test better this code and try to explain why it is happening.
The tip is to use `in` to check if the items exist in a list or not. `In` is more performatic than use a loop.
Exemplo working:

```
def binarysearch(elem, item):
    if item in elem:
        return elem.index(item)
    else:
        return -1 # because your if verifying if the return is equal or greater than 0.
```

**Update 1**
When I tried to run your code I got in one infinite loop, it's happening because of the expression `mid=int((low+u)/2)` - I couldn't understand why you did it. If we run this code happens this:

1. list [8,12,19,23] and Item 10
2. `u=len(l)-1` u  = 3 because 4 - 1
3. Get in the `while` because the condition is True
4. `mid=int((low+u)/2)` here `mid` will be (0+3)/2 as you force it to be int the result will be 1
5. `if item==l[mid]:` 10 == 12 -- l[mid] - l[1] - False
6. `elif item<l[mid]:` 10<12 True
7. `high=mid-1` high will be 1 - 1 = 0
8. You go to the next iteration starting on the number 3, and that is why you get in an infinite loop
   To go through all positions in a list, you could use the `low` that starts in 0 and increase if the `item` is not == the value in that position. So you could use the `while` but in that way:

```py
def binarysearch(l,item):
    low=0
    u=len(l)-1
    while low<=u:
        if item==l[low]:
            return low
        else:
            low+=1

    return -1
l=eval(input("Enter the list of elements"))
item=int(input("Enter search item:"))
index=binarysearch(l,item)
if index>=0:
    print(item,"found at index",index)
else:
    print("Element not found")
```

To debug your code you can use [1]: https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html